# Highest value since the start of the year pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this `df`

```
,date,id,value
0,1/1/2020,1,1
1,1/2/2020,1,10
2,1/3/2020,1,2
3,1/4/2020,1,11
4,1/5/2020,1,2
5,1/1/2021,1,1
6,1/2/2021,1,9
7,1/3/2021,1,5
8,1/4/2021,1,5
9,1/5/2021,1,5
10,1/6/2021,1,4
11,1/7/2021,1,2
12,1/8/2021,1,1
13,1/1/2020,2,20
14,1/2/2020,2,1
15,1/3/2020,2,25
16,1/4/2020,2,26
17,1/5/2020,2,1
18,1/2/2021,2,25
19,1/3/2021,2,26
20,1/4/2021,2,2
21,1/5/2021,2,3
22,1/6/2021,2,27
23,1/7/2021,2,1
24,1/8/2021,2,2
```

I need to get this `df2`

```
,date,id,value,max
0,1/1/2020,1,1,1
1,1/2/2020,1,10,10
2,1/3/2020,1,2,10
3,1/4/2020,1,11,11
4,1/5/2020,1,2,11
5,1/1/2021,1,1,1
6,1/2/2021,1,9,9
7,1/3/2021,1,5,9
8,1/4/2021,1,5,9
9,1/5/2021,1,5,9
10,1/6/2021,1,4,9
11,1/7/2021,1,2,9
12,1/8/2021,1,1,9
13,1/1/2020,2,20,20
14,1/2/2020,2,1,20
15,1/3/2020,2,25,25
16,1/4/2020,2,26,26
17,1/5/2020,2,1,26
18,1/2/2021,2,25,25
19,1/3/2021,2,26,26
20,1/4/2021,2,2,26
21,1/5/2021,2,3,26
22,1/6/2021,2,27,27
23,1/7/2021,2,1,27
24,1/8/2021,2,2,27
```

As you can see from `df2` I need maximum values for each day since the start of the year grouped by id and year. The problem is complicated also by the fact that the first day of a year does not always start from January 1. As you can see from `df` first day of 2021 for `id` 2 starts from January 2. Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this suffice:

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.assign(max = df.groupby(df.date.dt.year).value.cummax())

         date  id  value  max
0  2020-01-01   1      1    1
1  2020-01-02   1     10   10
2  2020-01-03   1      2   10
3  2020-01-04   1     11   11
4  2020-01-05   1      2   11
5  2021-01-01   1      1    1
6  2021-01-02   1      9    9
7  2021-01-03   1      5    9
8  2021-01-04   1      5    9
9  2021-01-05   1      5    9
10 2021-01-06   1      4    9
11 2021-01-07   1      2    9
12 2021-01-08   1      1    9
13 2020-01-01   2     20   20
14 2020-01-02   2      1   20
15 2020-01-03   2     25   25
16 2020-01-04   2     26   26
17 2020-01-05   2      1   26
18 2021-01-02   2     25   25
19 2021-01-03   2     26   26
20 2021-01-04   2      2   26
21 2021-01-05   2      3   26
22 2021-01-06   2     27   27
23 2021-01-07   2      1   27
24 2021-01-08   2      2   27
```

This assumes that the `date` column is sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cummax`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['date'], dayfirst=False, index_col=0)
df

df['max'] = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='Y', key='date'), 'id']) \
              .rolling(2, min_periods=1).max() \
              .droplevel(['date', 'id']).astype(int)

print(df)

# Output
         date  id  value  max
0  2020-01-01   1      1    1
1  2020-01-02   1     10   10
2  2020-01-03   1      2   10
3  2020-01-04   1     11   11
4  2020-01-05   1      2   11
5  2021-01-01   1      1    1
6  2021-01-02   1      9    9
7  2021-01-03   1      5    9
8  2021-01-04   1      5    5
9  2021-01-05   1      5    5
10 2021-01-06   1      4    5
11 2021-01-07   1      2    4
12 2021-01-08   1      1    2
13 2020-01-01   2     20   20
14 2020-01-02   2      1   20
15 2020-01-03   2     25   25
16 2020-01-04   2     26   26
17 2020-01-05   2      1   26
18 2021-01-02   2     25   25
19 2021-01-03   2     26   26
20 2021-01-04   2      2   26
21 2021-01-05   2      3    3
22 2021-01-06   2     27   27
23 2021-01-07   2      1   27
24 2021-01-08   2      2    2
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, chose another answer as correct since it was posted first

Comment: Ok. I understand. I updated my answer to give you an alternative.